# Why server got an error 500 when maximum execution time is more than 30?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter for a simple website .

My problem is that i can not run scripts that last more than 30 seconds , for example :

```
ignore_user_abort(false);   
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
set_time_limit(31);
while(true){
//smth here
}
```

When i use these code server give me an error 500 with nothing explainet , but when i run the script below it says that maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded.

```
ignore_user_abort(false);   
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
set_time_limit(29);
while(true){
//smth here
}
```

Why error is not the same in both cases ?
Im using a server that i don't have access in php.ini or error logs.

Comment: Many webservers also have their own time limit, and will timeout with a 500 if that is exceeded

Comment: could your try to change max_execution_time ?

Comment: Get access to the logfiles, it is absolutely important to have that, you cannot locate the source of a 500 error without access to the logfiles.

Comment: Yes  Ranjeet Singh I have tried that .
Mark Baker this is only in save mode ?